# Upgraded to mint 17, keyboard stuck in non-english (wrong layout) language - can't login

Tags: linux-mint, grub2

I had Linux Mint 16 with English and Russian keyboard support. Upgraded to Mint 17, now I cannot get past the ecryptfs passphrase.

If I enter Grub loader I can pick "Ubuntu with Linux 3.11.0.12-generic" and I am able to enter passphrase (latin characters) but when I get to Login Screen it only types in Russian. I changed the language to US English, British English, but it has no effect. Characters are still in Russian. (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJTTn.jpg)

I have searched LinuxMint forums up and down...fruitless.

Recovery console also drops into Russian and I cannot login either. so basically I have no access to system whatsover.

Also: I have tried "e" grub, and set locale=en_US.UTF-8 .........NO SUCCESS I have tried LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ............ same crap I have even tried passing en_US.ASCII to kernel.... still nothing.

Is there a way to pass charset UTF-8 in Grub config to kernel?

Comment: Are you able to log in on a text console? If yes, the linked answer should help solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this problem is affecting the console as well as login, it appears the system-wide settings have changed.

The key to getting around this is editing the keyboard settings by booting with a live cd/usb.

You can then edit the following file:

> /etc/default/keyboard

and replacing "ru" with "en":

> XKBLAYOUT="en"

A similar question & answer here:
[Mint login screen: wrong keyboard layout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136382/mint-login-screen-wrong-keyboard-layout)

Edit this file:
/etc/mdm/Init/Default

and add the following before the last line (reading "exit 0"):

setxkbmap en

Comment: I feel like a suggestion such as this would be better served as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I am going to try LiveCD. I don't have a blank CD on hand, so haven't tried that yet. Yeah, you're correct, once I get to the console with En keymap, i can fix this.. but getting to that console...well :) Thanks. I'll try that today.